# Input with type range not working on Google Chrome

Tags: angularjs, input, slider, mobile-angular-ui

I have an app that is Django in the backend, Angular for the front-end. I am facing an issue where in one of my templates I have an input with type range that is not showing up, but only in Google Chrome, and only when it is in a mobile view. It works in Firefox, and Safari and the slider will show up there, but in Chrome it is only visible on desktop screen widths. There is nothing in the error console to suggest that it might have anything to do with an Angular error, I say this because I am using mobile-angular-ui which is heavy on slide features, and since it appears to only be a mobile issue. I have also tried a couple of third party slider libraries such as http://rangeslider.js.org/ and https://github.com/dwyl/range-touch, but still nothing. My version of Chrome is 56.0.2924.87. Is this an issue that anyone else is having, or have experienced in the past ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it happening on iPhone?

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="10" step="2" value="6">
```

According to http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/forms.html#type-range, Safari, Chrome, and Opera all treat this as a slider control. (Sadly, the iPhone renders it as a simple text box. It doesn’t even optimize its on-screen keyboard for numeric input.) All other browsers simply treat the field as type="text", so there’s no reason you can’t start using it immediately.

Please refer https://www.wufoo.com/html5/types/8-range.html for checking the browser support.